# Mounting folder in Docker and excluding git repos

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to mount a src folder in a Docker container. I want to be able to save my code on my local machine. I also have several repos I need to clone down for the project that are also in the src folder. I can clone down the code into my src folder in the Docker file. But I dont want to save this code locally. Only the code i am developing. What is the best way to set this up in Docker?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount not src folder fully but specify the only folder you need